# Crystal report not working on iis manager

Tags: crystal-reports, report

Crystal report is not working on iis, It is working fine on develpment. When `deploying` on `IIS` it shows the error

```
"Failed to open the connection. Failed to open the connection. 
CrystalReport3 {42D76915-6C05-4970-A03D-B3ED787AE0FC}.rpt".
```

what is solution for this?

Comment: Are you using BusinessObjects Enterprise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution.
I just changed the User DNS to Server DSN.
Its working now.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

are you asking about your own pc or any other pc. if other pc then it is possible to get this error. 
1. this may be your remote sqlserver is not connected
2. your report version may be not right version for other pc.

check this.
http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=11696
http://forums.asp.net/t/997655.aspx/1